# Is there a best practice to pass functions in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have a little question regarding passing functions in react.

In this example I used a react component created by a co-worker.
I passed a function like this:

```
const myFunction = (id) => {}
    <Component {...{onClicked:myFunction}} />
```

When rendered this auto called my function..

Then I saw in the component it looked like this

```
onClicked={props.method(this.Id)}
```

I fixed this by just adding ()=> like so

```
onClicked={()=>props.method(this.Id)}
```

but I saw that my co-worker had solved the auto call like doing this

```
 const myFunction = (id) => () => {}
        <Component onClicked={this.myFunction} />
```

I have never seen this before and tried to google it, but could not find anything.

Is there a best practice for passing functions in react?

Comment: Probably opinion-based, but I'd prefer your solution over the colleague's.  Theirs, in my opinion, obfuscates the problem behind a function that returns a function.  Whereas yours followed the much more common (and, to me, clear and obvious) pattern of passing a function reference to the `onClicked` event.  Note also that strong TypeScript typing would make these issues clear as well.

Comment: Ok interesting, I also like my approach better, obviously :D. But with programming there is always different ways of doing things and its always good to learn :). Thx for making this clearer :)